# Why is my program skipping the gets() function?

Tags: c

I was studying for a quiz and while writing the code I faced a problem.

My code skips the `gets()` function. If I use `scanf` it wont skip but since I'm scanning a full name using `scanf` would be troublesome but `gets()` is skipped for some reason.

```
struct Conta{

    char nomeDoCliente[50];
    int numeroDeConta;
    float saldoDeConta;

};
struct Conta conta1;

int main()
{
            switch (menu()){
            case 1 :
                defDadosDeConta();
                break;
            case 2 :
                break;
            case 3 :
                break;

            }
}

int menu(){
    int escolha;
    puts("1 - Definir dados da conta.");
    puts("2 - Depositar Dinheiro.");
    puts("3 - Levantar Dinheiro.");
    puts("4 - Sair.");
    printf("Escolha a sua operação: ");
    scanf("%d", &escolha);
    return escolha;
}
defDadosDeConta(){
    printf("Insira o seu nome: ");
    gets(conta1.nomeDoCliente);
    puts("Dados de conta guardados com sucesso!");


}
```

Comment: [Why are you using `gets`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/10077)

Comment: Probably because scanf leaves the newline character in the buffer, so gets reads an empty line.

Comment: What do you mean by "skip"? What makes you think that `gets()` gets skipped?

Comment: "%d' says to stop at the first non-digit and leave it in the input stream.  So the newline at the end of that line is still waiting to be read.

Comment: Init the clients name with e.g. "uninitialised". Then see whether that survives. If the name ends up as "", i.e. empty, then `gets()` did **not** get skipped.

Comment: Im using gets cos i want to get a full name input from the user.

Comment: I used the fflush(stdin); at the end of every functoin i have in my code and it solved my problem.

Comment: It was indeed the scanf leaving a newline char in the buffer

Comment: Never mind it keeps skipping scanf's and gets (); 's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [never use `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) as it is insecure.  The safer alternative is `fgets`.

Even if you use that, mixing `scanf` and `fgets` causes problems because the former may leave a newline in the input buffer, causing the latter to stop once it reads that newline.

Change to `scanf` to read the string:

```
scanf("%49[^\n]", conta1.nomeDoCliente);
```

The format specifier `%49[^\n]` states to read up to 49 non-newline characters.

Comment: %49[^\n] did fix my problem. I think the issue was that after i canned for the conta1.nomeDoCliente some background issue were happening.